# There's a snake lies

Tags: riddle

> There's a snake lies.
>   In the void must be filled.
>   Hidden from the all conflict.
>   Ever wonder what could have been.

What/who am I describing?

Hint 1:

> Although it's not the conflict the snake avoiding, there's 2 side questioning each other about their ways.

Hint 2:

> One side hold a certain cud-chewing mammal in high regard.

Hint 3:

> You really should figure it out already, but in any case you don't, the answer is close by.

Comment: The grammar seems very strange in this poem. Is that intentional? (E.g. I would edit to "There a snake lies. / Hidden from all the conflict. / The void must be filled. / Ever wonder what could have been?" but I don't know if that would spoil the puzzle.)

Comment: No it's not. Yeah you're right. But i want to make so the snake is in the void

Comment: @Randal'Thor You are right. I think it isn't intentional. Even the rhyme scheme is strange. Only the second and third lines rhyme. Moreover, two consecutive lines don't seem to be much related except the second one from the first.

Comment: Eh I don't think I can make it rhyme. Not fluent in English enough.

Answer (score 1):

*2nd Attempt:*

Is it a

> [Chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28mythology%29)?

Actually I'm not pretty sure about it and this answer is only based on the 2 hints.

> Hint 1: The two sides are the lion and the goat
>
>  Hint 2: A goat is a ruminant which is a cud-chewing mammal

---

*1st Attempt:*

Is it a

> Nail? (used in construction)

There's a snake lies.

> Snake is the long part of the nail

In the void must be filled.

> Not sure of this one since we use nail in solid object not in hole, but it creates a hole(void) in the object once used.

Hidden from the all conflict.

Ever wonder what could have been.

> Conflict is the act of hammering the nail. Hidden since the head part of the nail is the one you are hammering and also hidden once the nail is hammered all the way down and it will not know what will happen next

Comment: why down vote, is it because my guess is wrong?

Comment: Don't know who down voted you, but yes this is not the answer I intended, good try though.

Comment: @Sinh check my other answer

Comment: Nope, try again.

Answer (score 1):

My geographical and political knowledge isn't great, but are you describing

> the Indus river?

There's a snake lies.
In the void must be filled.

> It is a winding river that passes through a valley

Hidden from the all conflict.
Ever wonder what could have been.

> It runs between India and Pakistan, and according to wikipedia
> it has a highly contested [treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indus_Waters_Treaty).

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> **Hole** Snake lives there, it has a void and it is hidden.

Though it is too simple.

Comment: nope, try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you..

> the Kashmir Valley region?

There's a snake lies.

> The snake could refer to the shape of the region or the region's disputed borders.

In the void must be filled.

> Parties involved feel they must take control of the territory.

Hidden from the all conflict.

> The current Kashmir conflict is not as well known in the West compared to other issues.

Ever wonder what could have been.

> Indeed one wonders what could possibly lie in store for the region if only there was peace.

Note:

> Honestly, I don't think I could've even attempted an answer here without the 2nd hint.

Comment: Nope! Try again. Rot13(V znqr uvag 2 orpnhfr V xvaqn jnag guvf evqqyr nafjrerq nyernql. Vg'f ernyyl n qrnq tvirnjnl. ).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are

> nāga or Nagi

Because:

> In Hinduism and Buddhism nāga are divine, semi-divine deities, or a semi-divine race of half-human half-serpent beings that reside in the netherworld and can occasionally take human form.

I base it on the hints:

> There are two sides of the story what they are and what they're able to (Hinduism and Buddhism). The Hindus adore cows which are cud-chewing mammals.

There's a snake lies.

> They are fully or partly snakes

In the void must be filled.

> Which side of the story is true? There must be an answer.

Hidden from the all conflict.

> Maybe this part is hidden from the religious conflicts of the world.

Ever wonder what could have been.

> What if one story got acknowledged? Or what if they are real? *Not sure about htat one*